# Order of a group?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a = g^{16}$. Assume $\operatorname{ord} g = 40$. Find $\operatorname{ord} a$.

Not sure how you would find $\operatorname{ord}a$. We did not go over this. Here is what I did

We know that $g^{16t}$ =1

The $ord$ $g$ divides $16t$

$40/16t$

$40/16t$ = $40$/$ $(16)(80)$ = $200$ because (16,40) = 80

The min $t$ is $80$.

Is this correct? Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Hint: The order of a power of en element can never be greater than the order of the element itself.

Comment: the minimum t such that $16t = 80$ is $5$. That is, the minimum $t$ such that $40$ divides $16t$ is $t = 5$, which is the order, then, of $a = g^{16}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $16t = \text{lcm}(16, 40) \tag{lcm least common multiple}$

Recall that if the order of $g$ is $40$, then we know $g^{40} = e$ and for all $m$ such that $0\lt m \lt 40$, $g^m \neq e$.

The minimum integer $16t$ such that $40$ divides $16t$ is the least common multiple of $16, 40$

$$16 = 2^4,\;\;40 = 2^3 \times 5 \implies \text{lcm}(16, 40) = 2^4 \times 5 = 80$$

So $16 t = 80 \implies t = 5$.

$$a^5 = (g^{16})^5 = g^{80} = g^{40\times 2} = e^2 = e$$

Comment: $\LARGE{+1}$ :-)

Comment: @amWhy: I second Babak's Huge +1! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's hardly ever a need to make things more complicated than they are. Don't try invoke gcd's or linear equations, when you don't need them.

You can just write successive powers of $a$: $a, a^2, \ldots$ as $g^{16}, g^{32}, g^8, g^{24}, g^{40}=1$. Which shows you what the order of $a$ is. This is basically what the first answer is telling you as well: $g^{\text{lcm}(40,16)}=1$, which is some power of $g^{16}=a$.